# Override or merge multiple jquery plugins

Tags: jquery

I have the following situation in one file:

HTML file:

```
-Master(unable to edit)-----------------------
-  include jquery 1.4.2
-  include old validator plugin
-  document ready
-    $("#form").validate({ settings1 })
-My code through CMS--------------------------
-  include jquery 1.8.3
-  include newest validator plugin
-  document ready
-    $("#form").validate({ settings2 })
```

I cant edit the master section with old scripts but i can override through embedded script. All goes well except validating somehow the function of settings2 gets ignored. Is there a posibility to merge settings1 and settings2. Or if not possible to override settings2 over settings1?

Thanks for the help

Comment: You're going about it the wrong way, instead of trying to figure out how you can add old crap to your site and still make it work, you should be figuring out how you could change "Master" and remove the old crap instead.

Comment: Which CMS do you use ?

Comment: I know, the situation sucks but for now there is no alternative changing the master. Its a temporarely solution until the 3rd party updates there code.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you cannot remove or update old stuff.
Therefore i suggest that you put your new feature in a dedicated part (specific html page, portlet, widget, iframe, ...) to only get references to your new specific versions.